# Transform spark string column to vectorUDT

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark.
First I'm reading a csv with a string column. The data inside looks like this :

> (174, [7, 10, 56, 89, 156], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

I need to transform it into a VectorUDT, to give the column as input to machine learning algorithms.

I have already tried to cast the column :

> data = data.withColumn(column, data[column].cast(VectorUDT())

But it's not working...


Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can try is to use VectorUDT's internal [_sqlType](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/VectorUDT.scala)(see below) to construct a JSON string and then use `from_json` function:

```
struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>
```

First, remove the leading and trailing parenthesis and split the string with regex `,\s*(?=\[)`. this will convert the StringType column into an ArrayType column named `s` with 3 items corresponding to *s[0]=size*, *s[1]=indices* and *s[2]=values*, and then use `concat` function to create the JSON string.

**Note:** in this example, we wrap up the VectorUDT with an **array** since from_json function only takes one of the complex datatypes: *array*, *map* or *struct*. you can try using *map* or *struct* as a wrapper as well.

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, from_json

df = spark.createDataFrame([('(174, [7, 10, 56, 89, 156], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])',)],['column'])
# DataFrame[column: string]

df_new = df.withColumn("s", expr("split(substr(column,2,length(column)-2), ',\\\\s*(?=\\\\[)')")) \
  .selectExpr("""
      concat(
        /* type = 0 for SparseVector and type = 1 for DenseVector */
        '[{"type":0,"size":',
        s[0],
        ',"indices":',
        s[1],
        ',"values":',
        s[2],
        '}]'
      ) as vec_json
   """) \
  .withColumn('features', from_json('vec_json', ArrayType(VectorUDT()))[0])
```

**Notice** that the JSON string we constructed here is an array with a single VectorUDT, we can then use `from_json` and `getItem(0)` to retrieve the vector.

### result:

```
df_new.printSchema()
root
 |-- vec_json: string (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)

df_new.show(truncate=False, vertical=True)
-RECORD 0---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 vec_json | [{"type":0,"size":174,"indices":[7, 10, 56, 89, 156],"values":[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]}]
 features | (174,[7,10,56,89,156],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
```